# How can I clear a QwtPlot on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

In my **QwtPlot** object I have some curves plotted and a **QwtPlotPicker** (derived from the curvetracker class from the Qwt playground).

**How can I clear it all?**

I need to remove the curves, hide the axes and remove the **QwtPlotPicker**.

I can remove the curves with the following command:

```
myQwtPlot->detachItems(QwtPlotItem::Rtti_PlotItem, true);
```

And I can hide/disable the axes with the following commands:

```
myQwtPlot->enableAxis(QwtPlot::xBottom, false);
myQwtPlot->enableAxis(QwtPlot::yLeft, false);
```

But I don't know how to remove the **QwtPlotPicker**. If I just remove the curves and move the mouse over my **QwtPlot** my application crashes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by **disabling** my **QwtPlotPicker**:

```
myQwtPlotPicker->setEnabled(false);
```

I don't know if it is the best/right solution, but it worked.

Anyway, if anyone knows a better way to do so please let me know.